# Cannot resolve symbol / in scala

Tags: scala, list, average, division

Hi I am trying to find average ratings of a list of ratings.

```
 val normalizedRatings = user_ratings.groupBy(a=>a._1).map{r=> (r._1,r._2.toList.map(x=>x._2))}
```

Here is how my normalizedRatings looks like.

(zZRze7w4iWJrj5XR_MVg0w,List(2.0, 4.0, 5.0))
...

When I try to run the program, '/' symbol throws an error.

```
val userAvgRating = normalizedRatings.map(x=>(x._1.toInt, x._2.sum/x._2.length))
```

I tried using `toFloat`

```
 val userAvgRating = normalizedRatings.map(x=>(x._1.toInt, x._2.sum.toFloat/x._2.length))
```

I got a similar error to

```
Error:(26, 68) could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[String]
    val userAvgRating = normalizedRatings.map(x=>(x._1.toInt, x._2.sum.toFloat/x._2.length))
```

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the type signature of `normalizedRatings`?

Comment: tuples like this:  (zZRze7w4iWJrj5XR_MVg0w,List(2.0, 4.0, 5.0)) ... basically id which is string and a list of ratings

Comment: Please post the exact signature. A word description isn't going to be of much help.

Comment: (GhAWojok71zu1JDhxjoRUw,List(4.0, 4.0, 2.0))
(vhBrattXdA1dy9hbBEAZCw,List(4.0))
(nugG6j8B4q0VpcPF9L4Iyw,List(3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0))
(RJiztqjMkY__TShC9Cjm6g,List(5.0))
(ZlV2g7DARR1xq6rS-HCBlw,List(4.0))
(NEgCKseWlPXSzPzH1s8TZA,List(4.0))
(RviTAd85NMC4SIvknqjcxQ,List(4.0))
(oSI_KvY86wb0KkJ10cBx1g,List(4.0, 4.0))
(IJ0Bl6UCbml-kHrOh97stA,List(4.0))
(U925qIx5BrjkOEsF6MsmYA,List(4.0, 4.0, 3.0))
(BJ0s4LpzlAVeAtZMV_y6og,List(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0))
(k_txnMRIFWXKxxX0ZXJg-g,List(3.0, 4.0))
(XPWiUNYQVOAlc255F5zVQw,List(3.0, 4.0))

Comment: val normalizedRatings = user_ratings.groupBy(a=>a._1).map{r=> (r._1,r._2.toList.map(x=>x._2.toDouble))}

Comment: This is not the type signature. This is a data sample/example. Also not of much help. I tried to run the data but got an error, unfortunately not the same error as you've posted. The error I get is from calling `toInt` on the `String` element.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me exactly what the type of `normalizedRatings` is (seems like some `Iterable` or `IndexedSeq` collection of `(String, List[Double])`. You might try...

```
val usrAvgRating = normalizedRatings map { case (id, ratings) => (id, ratings.sum / ratings.length) }
```

...if you can provide the exact type signatures if would be more helpful.  Note that you are calling `toInt` on a `String` at some point which is probably the source of the error.